# Converting date in SQL query to show just month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data:

```
INSERT INTO migrated (value, month) VALUES 
    (2, "2018-06-01"),
    (3, "2018-07-01");
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT `migrated`.`migrated_id` AS `migrated_id`, `migrated`.`month` AS `month`, `migrated`.`value` AS `value`
FROM `migrated`
LIMIT 2000
```

My graphing software is plotting it as Friday, 1st, June 2018

Apparently I need to change my SQL query to return it in a different format so that it changes in the graph.

**Question:**
How can I change my SQL query to return the name of the month in this format "Jun" for example, not showing the year or day.

Comment: What DBMS are you using (Oracle, MySql, etc.)?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Looks like mySQL. If so, please tag it in your question. thx

Comment: If you return just the month name, how will the graphing software know what order to put the data in?

Comment: @EstebanP. Sorry its mysql

Comment: @DRastislav Sorry how do I integrate that into my full SQL as above?

Comment: Use `MONTH(date)` to get the month of your date where "date" is your date column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  migrated_id,
  DATE_FORMAT(month, '%b') AS month,
  value
FROM migrated
LIMIT 2000
```